# Create a function to input array and output array semicolon separated in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I’m trying to make a function that inputs an array of strings and outputs the strings separated by a semicolons.
My string array looks like:

```
let stringArray = ["dog", "cat", "bird", "cow"]
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Are you thinking of `join`?

```
let joinedString = join(";", stringArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift has `join` built into `String` and `Array`, but it works backwards from how you might think:

```
let stringArray = ["dog", "cat", "bird", "cow"]
let delimited = ";".join(stringArray)
// not stringArray.join(";")
```

Comment: I keep pondering why the method-form of `join` works that way. It feels like there has to be some deep type-related reason, but I'm not coming up with anything. That seems horrible for chaining (which is the most useful part of using method rather than functions).

Comment: It doesn't read well, either - I want to join the array, not the glue.

Comment: Ah, I get why it's the way it is. If you try to implement `join` in the other direction, you have to constrain your `Array<T>` such that `T:ExtensibleCollectionType`. But you can't apply constraints inside an extension. Consider how `[1,2,3].join(4)` would be expected to work vs `["a","b","c"].join(",")`.

Comment: (which is why I think the function form is better than the method form in almost all cases.)

Comment: Argh. My least favorite part of Swift strikes again.